# Detect if a bot account goes offline/online

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am using the `presenceUpdate` event however, it is triggering twice, I am told it is emitting for how many shared servers I have with the bot. Currently my code outputs `online` twice. I am not sure on how to get it to output just once.

```js
if (newPresence.userID === botid) {
  if (newPresence.status === 'online') {
    console.log(newPresence.status); // Should output 'online' currently outputs 'online online'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [discord.js' docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate) `presenceUpdate` is `Emitted whenever a guild member's presence (e.g. status, activity) is changed.`

So it has nothing to do with how many shared servers you have with the bot.

You could try and check for the client's ping using [`Presence#status`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=status) every 5 minutes, you could write a function like this:

```js
function checkStatus() {
    if (client.users.fetch(botID).presence.status === "online" ) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
}
```

Then you can run this:

```
client.setInterval(() => checkPing(), 300000);
```

`300000` is 5 minutes in milliseconds, so every 5 minutes it'll run the function.

You can read more about [`client.setInterval()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=setInterval)

Comment: I believe due to it looking for activity changes too that it posts the results once for status and then for activity, here is `console.log(newPresence)` : https://pastebin.com/zzZLFkWv

Comment: You can see the change in `activity` compare line 65 and 132 in your pastebin link.

Comment: I am aware of the changes, what I want is the status, i.e. `online`. However, currently due to activity changes, it prints online twice. Line 64 & 131

Comment: I am confused, why did you give me code to check ping, I am looking to detect if another one of my bots goes offline.

Comment: Try the solution I just edited in, I think it'll work for you. You can also change the function to do whatever once you know it's offline, like sending an embed to a channel.

Comment: Still having issues with it posting twice, perhaps I am doing it wrong, I am not that great with functions, could you expand?

Comment: I am not using `presenceUpdate`, I essentially wrote a new "presenceUpdate" type of check that occurs once every 5 minutes

Comment: I appreciate the effort however, this is a workaround that I do not wish to add.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by simply comparing the status.

```js
  if (oldPresence.status === newPresence.status) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this remained unsolved, so I'll solve it for you.
So the answers above are correct, however, none of them states the intents the bot requires for this.

You see, `presenceUpdate` won't emit unless you have enabled the presence privilege gateway intent. For bots in less than 100 servers, this can be toggled on the developer portal by flipping a switch. Otherwise you need to open a ticket for discord to enable the presence intent.

Once you enable intents, try this:

```
client.on(`presenceUpdate`,(member)=>{
    console.log(`${member.user.username} has updated their presence.`)
})
```

Then try changing your status to dnd. If you enabled it, you should see
`[your tag] has updated their presence.`. Otherwise you may have done something wrong.