# How to tell when a bot is conected in python?

Tags: discord.py, connection

I'm making a bot for discord in discord.py and giving the compiled executable to friends, so I want to know when the bot is already connected to discord to prevent bugs, I thought to use a server but I don't think it will be usefull for me(because I don't know anything of server stuff xD).
is there any way to detect when the bot is connected without connecting a second instance of it? or any example of connection to a server that I can modify to my use?

please and thank you.

my english is broken btw xD.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66863177/check-if-discord-bot-is-online) about what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, but I need it to be across machines

Comment: Across all what machines?

Comment: every machine I share the executable with